# CouchDB on Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS: Stop and restart

Tags: couchdb

I am in the process of evaluating CouchDB for a specific requirement and I am new to CouchDB.

I have installed Couch DB using the package installation and it has started at the time of installation and listening to port 5984.

Now i want to stop and restart. I have tried various options but none of them worked.

Option 1

> sudo service couchdb stop (this does not stop at all)
>
> sudo netstat -lpn shows that a process listening to 5984

Option 2

> sudo -i -u couchdb /etc/init.d/couchdb start

**This is prompting for the password (ofcourse) which i do not know.**

I understand that a new user called couchdb is created at the time of installation. 
**What is the default password of this user?**

Comment: Even the following command does not work
"ps -U couchdb -o pid= | xargs kill -9"

Strangely these work
"reboot
sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb stop"

The out put from ps -ef suggested to restart the server using "sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb stop" but again cannot stop without reboot.

I am surprised why stopping the server is a mystery and its not documented well enough.

Comment: Which version of CouchDB did you install? AFAIK, the default installed one is 1.1, is this the one that you installed? Doing it as `root` (using sudo) should stop it no matter it has been initiated by another user.

Comment: I did a package installation on ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS and i see Couch 1.0.1 got installed. Sudo is prompting me for a password.

Comment: When you run `sudo` the password that it prompts for is your own password.

Comment: Let me make it clear. I was talking about option 2 where it prompts for the couchdb passowrd. 
With Option 1, it really does not stop the server. It says "* Stopping database server couchdb [ OK ]", but "sudo netstat -lpn" shows that the server is still running.

Comment: Since I'm not having the same problem, lets see how I can help you. 1. While running couchdb, who is the user that runs the server, is `couchdb` or `root`? 2. If you do `sudo -s` you change to `root`, then you can change the password to `couchdb` user and set whichever you want (use `passwd couchdb`). 3. Check if as `couchdb` user you can stop the service. **BTW** did you realize than in option 2 you say `start` and not `stop`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22505/discussion-between-onabai-and-manikandankannan)

Answer (score 13):

First, you simply need to reboot Ubuntu.  If CouchDB is running after an install, it is, so far as I can tell, impossible to kill it.  Once you reboot, you can use
`sudo service couchdb stop`
  and then
`sudo service couchdb start`.

Second, there is no password when CouchDB is first installed, so I believe the fact that it prompts you is a bug.  You can go to

```
http://localhost:5984/_utils
```

and then click on the 
"Fix this" link in the bottom right corner of the screen, where it says "Admin party", to set the first password.

See [CouchDB: The Definitive Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Is I was young, they' said "There are only 2 reasons for rebooting Linux: installing net not P&P hardware and installing new kernel". Did it change meanwhile? In any case for me rebooting is not an option, as other services also run on my server.

Answer (score 9):

I was having this same problem, and found [this](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/server/common.html#post--_restart) in the CouchDB docs: To restart the server you must do a POST to the special URL `<server>/_restart` while authenticated as an admin user.

Example with curl:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5984/_restart -H"Content-Type: application/json"
```

**NOTE:** [This method is no longer supported in CouchDB 2.0+](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1047)

Comment: This is no longer supported:
https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/1047

Answer (score 1):

I think you must do this as root. The rc script will switch as appropriate to the couch user

Comment: It really does not stop the server.It says "* Stopping database server couchdb [ OK ]", but "sudo netstat -lpn" shows that the server is still running.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new user in the **/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini** file

```
[admins]
;admin = mysecretpassword
myNewUsername = myNewPassword
```

I then rebooted Ubuntu, once back in Ubuntu I ran:

```
sudo service couchdb stop
sudo service couchdb start
```

I then logged in couchdb using:

```
http://localhost:5984/_utils/index.html#login
```

I logged in with mynewusername and mynewpassword and then ran verify installation on:

```
http://localhost:5984/_utils/index.html#/verifyinstall
```

It then worked, but then the password in the local.ini was not encrypted after I restarted ubuntu. But it was encrypted in the:

```
http://localhost:5984/_utils/index.html#_config/couchdb@127.0.0.1
```

I was expecting it would be encrypted in the file