# How to [start|stop|restart] couchdb in cloud9?

Tags: couchdb, ubuntu-14.04, cloud9-ide

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and I just want to restart (stop and start) couchDB, which is running on cloud 9. I tried these but none of them seems to work:

1.

```
ps -U couchdb -o pid= | xargs kill -9
```

2.

```
sudo couchdb stop
```

3.

```
curl -X POST http://[username]:[password]@127.0.0.1:5984/_restart -H"Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: Did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232276/couchdb-on-ubuntu-12-0-4-lts-stop-and-restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting the couchdb the way the [Cloud9 doc](https://docs.c9.io/docs/setting-up-couchdb) says will allow a simple `Control + C` to close it:

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/couchdb
sudo chown couchdb:couchdb /var/run/couchdb 
sudo su couchdb -c /usr/bin/couchdb
```

[image]

However is that's not what you want you can always find the `PID` and `kill` it:

```
mikeumus@couchdb:~/workspace (master) $ pstree -ap|grep couchdb

    |       |-grep,9050 --color=auto couchdb
              `-sudo,9018 su couchdb -c /usr/bin/couchdb
                  `-su,9019 couchdb -c /usr/bin/couchdb
                      `-beam.smp,9020 -Bd -K true -A 4 -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/couchdb ---noshe

mikeumus@couchdb:~/workspace (master) $ sudo kill -- -9018

mikeumus@couchdb:~/workspace (master) $ pstree -ap|grep couchdb
      |       |-grep,9071 --color=auto couchdb
```

[image]

Don't mind the color process still running, the couchdb process is now off. If you want to find and kill the couchdb in a single command, try:

`kill $(ps aux | grep '[c]ouchdb' | awk '{print $2}')`

Explained in this Stack Overflow Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510850/1762493